# how to check which UIButton has been selected

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to figure out which UIButton has been selected, out of a bunch, (10) buttons that are selectable and are hooked up to the same IBAction method.. however I'm not sure how to do this..

I was woundering if there was an attribute I can set in each button that would allow me to check when getting the sender(id) back from the IBAction.. however all that gives me are the basic details of the UIButton.

```
<UIRoundedRectButton: 0x1c576e70; frame = (20 8; 57 57); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5931e0>>
```

Also as a side note each UIButton is hooked up via an IBOutlet.. but I am not sure how I can use this to check which UIButton has just been selected...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `:(id)sender` to your `IBAction` method.  Test if `sender == buttonName` for each of the 10 buttons.  When true, you have found the correct button.

Comment: this worked.. dunno why I didn't try it myself.. Thanks for helping me out :P

Comment: Not very scalable, but quick and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you have an action, it looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick(id)sender;
```

or

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick(UIButton *)sender;
```

if only `UIButtons` can call it.
So `sender` will be the button who got clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IBOutletCollection` to maintain your list of buttons. When you receive the message from any of the buttons, you can get the index from the array.

Declare a property of buttons (and synthesize it in the `@implementation`, and add the buttons in IB like you would to a single `IBOutlet`):

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

In your action method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    // sender = button that fired the action
    NSInteger index = [self.buttons indexOfObject:sender];
    // ... do more stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags. When you alloc your buttons or when you place them in IB , you can set them each a tag: 1,2,3,4...etc. Then , when the selector gets called (the selector should look like this: `- (IBAction) onButton:(id)sender;` ) you can get the tag like this:

`UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *) sender;`

`NSLog(@"you pressed button %d",pressedButton.tag);`

Cheers,
George

Answer (score 0):

Very simple...

```
    if([myButton isSelected])
    {
        NSLog(@"Selected!");
    }
```